# Причастный оборот

Tags: синтаксис

здравствуйте! возник спор по поводу наличия в предложении причастного оборота:
рассказ пронизан языческой символикой,которая к тому же очень враждебна князю:языческие жрецы-"кудесники" предрекают ему смерть от его собственного коня.
спасибо

Answer (score 6):

Говоря о причастном обороте, имеют в виду полное причастие с зависимым словом (распространенное определение). В данном случае причастие краткое, выполняет роль сказуемого.

Answer (score 1):

> здравствуйте! возник спор по поводу наличия в предложении причастного оборота: рассказ пронизан языческой символикой,которая к тому же очень враждебна князю:языческие жрецы-"кудесники" предрекают ему смерть от его собственного коня. спасибо

Извините меня за это замечание. 
  Просто удивляет, что  в таком грамотно составленном вопросе, с приветствием и благодарностью, предложения начинаются со строчной буквы.